# IIS server configuration - Website performance issue

Tags: iis-7

```html
<!--

.Net CRL Version  =    v.4.0
Enable 32-Bit Applications  = False 
Managed Pipeline Mode = Integrated
Queue Length = 1000
Start Mode = AlwaysRunning

CPU
Limit (percent) = 0
Limit Action = noAction 
Limit interval (minutes) = 5
Processor Affinity Enable = false 
Processor Affinity Mask = 4294967295
Processor Affinity Mask(64-bit option) = 4294967295

Process Model 
General Process Model Event Log Entry
Idle Time out Reached  = True 
Identity = Administrator 
Idle Time-out (minutes) = 20
Idle Time-out Action = Suspend 
Load User Profile = True 
Maximum Worker Processes = 0
Ping Enable = True 
Ping Maximum Response Time (seconds) = 90
Ping Period (seconds) =  30
Shutdown Time Limit (seconds) = 90 
Startup Time Limit (seconds) = 90
I will send the setting in text format later , but regarding what happens between "better" and "worst" I am stressing the website with 4 or 5 users logging and doing some actions like filling forms submitting data.
Process orphaning 
Enable  = False 
Executable = 
Excutable Paramiters

Rapid – Fail Protection 
“Service Unavailable” Response type = HttpLevel 
Enable =  True 
Failure interval (minutes)= 5
Maximum Failures = 5
Shutdown Executable 
Shutdown Executable Parameters

Recycling
Disable Overlapped Recycle = False 
Disable Recycle for Configuration Changes = False 

Private memory Limit (KB) = 0
Regular Time Interval (minutes)
Request Limit 
Specific time= 7 hours 
Virtual memory Limit (KB)= 0


-->
```

Vb website slow on the IIS7, server 2016.

If I recycle the App pool the website performs better and then after some time it get worst again.

Can you please help me to understand what is the issue and if this is due to the incorrect setting of the App pool  ?

Also I have been suggested to change the value of Maximum Worker Processes to match with the number of cores. But after I have changed this the application started killing the session every 2 or 3 second and showing the login page. Can somebody help me to find why this is happening?

Please see the below App pool setting

[Apppool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6zpy.jpg)

[Apppool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq54U.jpg)

[Apppool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz76J.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: Please share your settings in text form, and describe what happens between "better" and "worst"

Comment: Thank you Nico for your reply.

Comment: I will send the setting in text format later , but regarding what happens between "better" and "worst" I am stressing the website with 4 or 5 users logging and doing some actions like filling forms submitting data.

Comment: Please share your settings in text form: I have updated my post with requested data.

Comment: IIS settings won't help much if your site is slow. Run a profiler and carefully analyze its performance (with the developers if possible) and that's the only effective way to locate bottlenecks and find out solutions to address them. Too broad for SO.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.